# When I git clone : fatal: does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, ssh

Why I always got "fatal: does not appear to be a git repository" when I use git push,show,fetch,clone.

I use repo to be my bare repository.

```
git remote add origin user@dev.com:/home/administration/repo
git push origin master
fatal: '/home/administration/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have tried many pattern with my remote url.

like

```
user@dev.com/home/administration/repo
user@dev.com//home/administration/repo
ssh://user@dev.com/home/administration/repo
```

However,all of the result were the same.

Steps:

```
-Server(user@dev.com/home/administration/)
    $ mkdir repo
    $ cd repo
    $ git init --bare
    Initialized empty Git repository in /home/administration/repo/
    $ ls -a
    .  ..  branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
-local
    $ git clone user@dev.com:/home/administration/repo
    warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.(repo directory has been created at local)
    $ cd repo
    $ git remote add origin user@dev.com:/home/administration/repo
    $ git remote -v
    origin  user@dev.com:/home/administration/repo (fetch)
    origin  user@dev.com:/home/administration/repo (push)
```

I just remove my .git directory that was created by vsCode at local.

Then it works.

I can clone the repo.

Howerver,I still can't push by vsCode.

When I use vsCode push,it returns

> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> user@dev.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I guess it's the password problem with ssh,but I can't type password in vsCode.

I try @VonC's method

My OS is Win10

```
-local
    > ssh-keygen
    Generating public/private rsa key pair.
    Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
    Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
    Enter same passphrase again:
    Your identification has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu.
    Your public key has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu.pub.
    The key fingerprint is:
    SHA256:nNnQckFbuegUs4WD3y+7YqwCaDhfUlX2J17jxF7X3FU xenby@demo.com
    The key's randomart image is:
    +---[RSA 2048]----+
    |       .o++ ..  E|
    |      .  *o+.  ..|
    |     .  = *+ o ..|
    |    .  . Ooo+ * +|
    | . o    Soo..B o.|
    |o + o     . ..o  |
    | + o .   .  . .  |
    |  .   .   +  o   |
    |       ..o .o.   |
    +----[SHA256]-----+
    > cp C:\Users\UserName\.ssh\id_rsa.pub C:\Users\UserName\authorized_keys
-Server
    > mkdir ~/.ssh
-local(Windows doesn't exist "ssh-copy-id",so I use scp)
    > scp authorized_keys user@dev.com:~/.ssh
    user@dev.com's password:
-Server
    > chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    > chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After I did these things,I still need to key password when I use ssh user@dev.com....

What is my problem?

Comment: Did you create that remote as `git init --bare`?

Comment: Does the target repo folder contain a .git folder?

Comment: could you please tap : "git config --list" command  and show the result ? and "git show"  command.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Yes,I did.

Comment: From what I see, the URL is parsed correctly, but points to something that is not a git repository.

Comment: I will show my step.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [VSCode SSH troubleshooting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent) page, if your private key is passphrase-protected, you should have an ssh-agent started first.

But if you can push manually, but have to enter the user password (as opposed to the key passphrase), that actually means the public key was not added to `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

That should not be your issue if you can clone. And if you can clone, you don't have to do a `git remote add origin ...`: the remote origin is *already* set during the clone.

Comment: As I searched before,there were so many responses like you answered me.
I can't use the root on server,so I want to ask for another answer.
Well...it seems that this is the only answer.

Comment: @Sanji Did you lepft the passphrase empty when generating the new key?

Comment: yeah,I key nothing

Comment: Can you type GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v", and then launch VScode from that same CMD session in order to inherit that variable. Then open the Git console in VSCode, and try to push: you should see logs about the ssh connection.

Comment: Still get the same response.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user@dev.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @Sanji With ssh -v, you should see *a lot* more logs, though.

Comment: Sorry,I'm not sure what do you mean. I only can type GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" in git Bash,then I open VScode to push.However,I get the response what I just post.

Comment: VSCode needs to be opened from the same CMD session. If not, try and set that variable as user variables in windows, then open VSCode again.

Comment: Now I can use git bash in VScode,then I type the command GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v".
I can type command and key password to push with the git bash in VScode.
But when I use the git in VScode ,I still get the same reponse,not more.

Comment: git log in VScode
> git push -u origin b1
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user@dev.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1):

### Create a local GIT Repository in your local file system

From the directory where you want to host your remote repoistory location

- `git init --bare repoName.git`  creates a repo called as repoName.git that can be used as a remote along with all required files inside

From the directory where you can want to hook up to the remote repository, having a valid GIT enabled project code

- `git remote add origin "/path/to/my/repoName.git"` add the path to the above create remote repository
- `git remote -v` to check the remote localtion path is correct
- `git push --set-upstream origin master` to push the code and set the upsteam as the branch master
- `git push origin` all later push syntax

#### To clone this repository in a new directory

From the new directory

- `git clone "path/to/my/repoName.git" newDirName` clones the repository into a new Directory

Comment: Thx for your answer,but I think it didn't catch my point.

Comment: @Sanji, can you please try setting up the local cloned repository on the server itself to ensure that the commands and connections are valid?

Comment: I can not only clone the repository now,but also can push my commit by git bash.
However,I want to use VScode without enter password to push my commit.
This question is bothering me now.

Comment: Have you set the following configuration for your git:  `git config --global user.name = "<name>"` and `git config --global user.email = "<email>"`

Comment: Yes,I have.I could see my user.name in commit log.

Comment: What is exactly path in?:
git clone user@server:path/to/my/repo